# In DB MySQL the index already exists for the column, should I add the index in the Hibernate Entity?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, indexing, entity

If the column has already the index "INDEX_VALUE" in DB MySQL.

Do I still need to add in hiberante Entity?

```
@NamedQuery(name = "", query = "SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.value = :value ")
@Table(...
indexes = { @Index(name = "INDEX_VALUE", columnNames = { "value" })})
public class Entity {
}
```

If I don't add this index in the entity, does it affect the search efficiency of @NamedQuery?

Answer (score 0):

`@Index` is used in schema generation to specify creation of an index.
So if you have already created the index it the DB through an SQL script, declaring it in the Entity won't make a difference.

This index does not affect the named query because the named query search for the value column but the index references the status column.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've made a mistake when creating my question. In fact the query and index are both for the column 'value'.    As I understand, `@Index` is only for generation, it has no influence on seraching efficiency of  `@NamedQuery`. In our App, in the code `Entity` there is no declaration of index for `value`, but in the DB there is index for `value`. This table is more than 12Gb, the simple search ` SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.value = :value ` takes more than 40 seconds. I haven't found the reason. Thank you again.

Comment: Is the value unique? Because if there are many records with this value and hibernate tries to fetch for example 1 million records from the database, then it is possible that it will still take some time. If you try to select a record with the primary key then how much time does it take?

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are run in MySQL server eventually
no matter where you execute them from.

```
@Index
```

will help you while creating or updating an schema (of course when hbm2ddl configuration is set set to update or create-drop.

Hence, it makes no difference using @Index in your entity while you database schema already has the column indexed.